# Beginner help: The system cannot find the path specified

Tags: dart

I'm just starting to use Dart in Visual Studio code and having some problems.

I've gone into Visual Studio Code, gone to File-->Open Folder..then created a folder with another folder inside, and then selected it. Then I downloaded package-simple through the terminal.Then when I go to explorer, I see that there is already pre-made code..ie under lib, src, there is a simple_console_example.dart file.

When I try to run this file I get a bin/main.dart:1: Error: The system cannot find the path specified.

Any help is appreciated!

Comment: "Then I downloaded package-simple" please post the link. No idea what package-simple is supposed to be.

Answer (score 6):

If you're running flutter extension in visual studio code for a sub-root directory, then debugging may yield the error whereas `flutter run` would work.

Solution is to open the sub-directory as folder in visual studio code.

---

If you're having this error for no apparent reason, try running commands below in the root directory of the project as suggested in [this solution](https://github.com/flutter/flutter/issues/17741#issuecomment-393636486):

```
flutter clean & flutter run
```

Answer (score 0):

Running

```
flutter clean & flutter run
```

from a terminal worked but it didn't fix the issue that I couldn't run a Debug session from within Visual Studio Code. The fix that did it for me was:

> The solution is to delete .vscode folder inside your project

which I found here: [Issue #29589 on Flutter Github Project](https://github.com/flutter/flutter/issues/29589)

Answer (score 0):

I have the same problem. find out that in my visual studio code at the explorer, i opened the wrong folder for my project. make sure your visual studio code is opening your folder project at the explorer nav bar on the left. File=>Open Folder=>"your project folder file.